# Long returned as string from Elastic makes Nest crash

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have an application that used Nest for like the pas 3-5 years. Until now, everything was working perfectly but now, when I get my results, it complains that

```
Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException: expected:'Number Token', actual:'"10770"', at offset:79299 ---> Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.JsonParsingException: expected:'Number Token', actual:'"10770"', at offset:79299
   à Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.JsonReader.ReadInt64()
   à Elasticsearch.Net.Utf8Json.JsonReader.ReadInt32()
   à Deserialize(Object[] , JsonReader& , IJsonFormatterResolver )
   [...]
```

In C#, my property is set as int and in Kibana, I can see that the field is set as long (I know, it isn't the same type but the value never goes above int limit).

From what I tested, the problem comes from the fact there are double quotes around the number effectively making it a string. I did 2 separate tests:

1. change the property type to string in C#
2. remove the double quotes in the json returned (using Fiddler)

and both times, it worked.

So my question is: why is Elastic all of a suddn adding double quotes around my numbers?

I'm using Nest 7.13.2 but unfortunately, I can't find how to get the version of Elastic through the APIs.